# Given O(n) sets, what is complexity of figuring out distinct ones amongst them?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have an application where I have a list of `O(n)` sets.

Each set `Set(i)` is an `n-vector`. Suppose `n=4`, for instance,

`Set(1)` could be `[0|1|1|0]`

`Set(2)` could be `[1|1|1|0]`

`Set(3)` could be `[1|1|0|0]`

`Set(4)` could be `[1|1|1|0]`

I'd like to process these sets so that as output, I only get the unique ones amongst them. So, in the example above, I would get as output:

`Set(1), Set(2), Set(3)`. Note that `Set(4)` is discarded since it is same as `Set(2)`.

A rather brute force way of figuring this gives me a worst-case bound of `O(n^3)`:

```
Given: Input List of size O(n)
Output List L = Set(1)

for(j = 2 to Length of Input List){ // Loop Outer, check if Set(j) should be added to L
    for(i = 1 to Length of L currently){ // Loop Inner
       check if Set(i) is same as Set(j) //This step is O(n) since Set() has O(n) elements
       if(they are same) exit inner loop
       else
            if( i is length of L currently) //so, Set(j) is unique thus far
                  Append Set(j) to L               
    }
 }
```

There is no a priori bound on `n`: it can be arbitrarily large. This seems to preclude use of simple hash function which maps the binary set into decimal. I could be wrong.

Is there any other way this can be done in better worst-case running time other than `O(n^3)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O(n) sequences of length n makes an input of size O(n^2).  You won't get complexity better than that, since you may at least be required to read all the input.  All sequences might be the same, for example, but you'd have to read them all to know that.

A binary sequence of length n can be inserted into a trie or radix tree, while checking whether or not it already exists, in O(n) time.  That's O(n^2) for all the sequences together, so simply using a trie or radix tree to find duplicates is optimal.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie
and: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree

Comment: Wow. This does seem optimal. Is there any space tradeoff with @Tim Biegeleisen's answer that has a higher complexity? Also, the index of the 1s in each of the distinct sets is rather important to me in my application. In retrieving distinct keys, in a Trie, is the index of the 1s also easily retrievable once done?

Comment: With a binary alphabet, a radix tree is space-efficient -- at least as good as a BST.  I'm not entirely sure what you mean about the indexes of the 1s, but the answer will surely be that it won't be difficult to achieve it.

Comment: What I mean by the index is that in the OP, when I am processing the output list, I will process Set(1) (suppose indices are L to R) then indices of 1;s are 1 and 2. Next, I process Set(2) of output, I need to be able to obtain indices 0, 1, 2, for instance and so on.

Comment: I should mention that you can also insert into a BST in O(n) time if you don't start every comparison from index 0 -- you have to avoid comparing prefixes that have already been determined to be equal.

Comment: It's easy to read each string out of the radix tree to determine the indexes of all the 1s.  If 1s are sparse and you need them more quickly, you can record their positions in the leaves.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider implementing your set using a balanced binary tree.  The cost of inserting a new node into such a tree is `O(lgm)`, where `m` is the number of elements in the tree.  Duplicates would implicitly be weeded out because if we detect that such a node already exists, then it would just not be added.

In your example, the total number of lookup/insertion operations would be `n*n`, since there are `n` sets, and each set has `n` values.  So, the overall time might scale as `O(n^2*lg(n^2))`.  This outperforms `O(n^3)` by some amount.

Comment: So, if each set was a scalar key, then inserting a new key (after deciding that it actually needs to be inserted) is O(log n). But in this case, because each set is a n-vector, the above operation becomes O(log n^2). Am I right? Then, I get O(n^2) in terms of outer and inner loops so the net is O(n^2 log n^2). Is my understanding of your argument correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I think the complexity is roughly `O(n*n*lgn)`, still a bit better than what you currently have.

Comment: this should not consider! he already had an application, you need to understand he can't create another ds for implementing the outcomes! creating another ds, doesn't entertaining here, i guess!

Comment: @ReturnZero In general, for someone reading this question, changing data structure to achieve better performance is something which actually _would_ be entertained.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, these are not sets but bitstrings.

Next, for every bitstring you can convert it to a number and put that number in a hashset (or simply store the original bitstrings, most hashset implementations can do that). Afterwards, your hashset contains all the unique items. O(N) time, O(N) space. If you need to maintain the original order of strings, then in the first loop check for each string if it is in the hashset already, and if not, output it and insert in the hashset.

Comment: I want to be able to know the index of the 1's. If I store them in an array or vector, the index of where the 1s feature is important to me. Figuring out the 1's is an O(n) operation in a set (array or vector with 0/1's). Is it easy to do that in bitstrings?

Comment: Your items are bitstrings. It is completely up to you how you store them. In C++'s STL, for instance, there are two specialized classes for this purpose: `std::bitstring` and a specializaion of `std::vector<bool>`.

Comment: I am unsure about every bitstring can be converted into a number part. What if n were 100000? It is not clear to me any hash function can convert that to a number representible in a machine. Won't there be collissions to worry about ? That would not make this O(n) is my guess.

Comment: Again, in that very STL hash functions are defined for all standard types, IIRC, so you can keep the strings directly, without converting to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use O(n) extra space, you can try this:

First of all, let's assume the vectors are binary numbers, so 0110 becomes 6.

- This is in case numbers in vectors are [0,1], else you can multiply by 10 instead of 2.

Converting all vectors into decimals would take O(4n).
For each converted number we'll map the vector by the decimal number. To implement this, we'll be using an n-sized hash-map.

1. HM <- n-sized hash-map
2. for each vector v:
   num <- decimal number converted of v
   map v into HM by num
3. loop over HM and take only one for each index

runtime by steps:

1. O(n)
2. O(n*(4+1)) , when 1 is the time for mapping, 4 is the vector length
3. O(n)

Comment: But there can be no a priori bound on n. So, what if n were 1000. 2^1000 cannot be adequately represented.

Comment: You can try sorting the vectors using radix sort, this would take O(kn), when k is the number of vectors and n is the length of each vector. After the vectors are sorted, you can iterate over the sorted vectors array and avoid duplicated ones (check if prev == curr or something like that).